# Can not migrate a new model using Rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to create a new table using rails 3. First i created model as `rails g model Vendor name:string address:string`. When typed rake db:migrate` it gave me the following error.

> Error: Mysql::Error: Table 'users' already exists

```
C:\Site\swargadwara_puri>rake db:migrate
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) D
EFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `contact_name` varchar(255), `login_id`
varchar(255), `password_hash` varchar(255), `password_salt` varchar(255), `phone
` varchar(255), `address` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated
_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDBC:/Site/swargadwara_puri/db/migrate/2015041
9131135_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
```

20150419131135_create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :contact_name
      t.string :login_id
      t.string :password_hash
      t.string :password_salt
      t.string :phone
      t.string :address

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have a table named as User in the same database before. I tried also command `rake db:migrate VERSION=201504......` still getting the same error. Please help me to resolve this error and create a new table successfully.

Comment: You already have `users` table. Check where it comes from.

Comment: @Marek,I already have users table but i am creating a new table(i.e.Vendor) inside same database where user is present.

Comment: So how do you want to name your newe table?

Comment: @Marek,I just typed rails g model Vendor name:string.When i typed rake db:migrate it throws error.

Comment: What does `bundle exec rake db:abort_if_pending_migration` return? Did you add any migration recently? I see in your error message that you have `create_users` migration created 4 days ago. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Marek , Yes i have created users migration 4 days ago.But iam not getting you about where does it come from.

Comment: @rajat_474 : You have already created User table before and your `20150419131135_create_users.rb` file try to generate it again. Thus you are getting an error. Let me know that do you required this file currently? If not then just delete it or comment everything in this file and then try rake db:migrate. It will works for you

Comment: @Gagan , Yes i need also 20150419131135_create_users.rb file currently.

Comment: Can you please post that file so I get idea what you wanted to do with your user table?

Comment: @Gagan , I dont want do anything with user tabel i was just creating a new model and at time of migrating I got this type of error.

Comment: Does your current db contains User Table with same structure? If yes then there is no need of this `20150419131135_create_users.rb` as this will again try to create User table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76007/discussion-between-rajat-474-and-gagan-gami).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in this case is that you have already created `User` table and your `20150419131135_create_users.rb` migration file try to create again User table. So I suggest that you take a backup of this file in your local system. Then temporary remove this file from your db/migration directory. And then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

it will solve your problem.

Now, as you said in chat that you have not any other migration file for create_user , I think you may lost your migration file which was created before while creating `User` table or you may created User table in different way(not by `rake db:migrate` as you don't have any other file like this in ur migration directory).

So, Follow this:

1. export the User table's data from MYSql and save that file on your system.
2. Drop the User table from MYSql
3. again put that temporarily removed `20150419131135_create_users.rb` file in db/migrate directory
4. run `rake db:migrate` which will create your `User` table
5. Import User data in User table which was exported in Step 1

In this way your issue of migration will be resolved forever and you will not even lost your existing data of `User` table.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in fussy but it works when i get this error,

Comment out you migrations `def up` content. execute `rake db:migrate` then `rake db:rollback` up to your commented migration version. then un-comment that `def up` method content and execute `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

you can drop the database and create again like

> `rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate`